# useRouter query returns undefined inside getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using useRouter to get some data from user in the query. I can see the query data in the form of HTML. But when I pass that `search` inside `getServerSideProps` it returns undefined.

```js
function SearchData() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { search } = router.query
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{search}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}


export async function getServerSideProps({search}) {
    console.log(search)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) function takes in a `context` as a parameter and the `context` has a `query` object which gives you access to your query string.

So instead of destructuring `search` consider destructuring `query` and using it like this

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
    console.log(query.search)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not suppose to pass search in getServerSideProps.

When you visit http://localhost/page?search=abc, you can retrieve abc from query.search

```
export async function getServerSideProps({query}) {

  console.log('req.query', query)

  //do something with the parameter. in this instance - query.search

  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

If you are not using serverSideProps and you want to get the search query string, you need to use useEffect, and wait for router to be ready.

Example

```
  const [ query, setQuery ] = useState()
  const router = useRouter()
  useEffect(() => {

        if (router.isReady) {

            setQuery(router.query)
            //query.search will then contain the search param
        }

    }, [router])
```